# Ubuntu 18.04 installed via Vagrant and latest packages

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

I've installed Vagrant on Win 10, edited /etc/apt/sources.list (grabbed from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/h0bbel/4b28ede18d65c3527b11b12fa36aa8d1)), but when I type `apt list php7.3*|more`, the list is empty.

On real physical server with the same Ubuntu 18.04 installed, and the same contents of /etc/apt/sources.list, it lists php7.3 packages.

Why it doesn't list the same packages on my Ubuntu installed via Vagrant?

Edit: After edit /etc/apt/sources.list I did `apt-get update`. It seemed to update packages list but it didn't matter, I still don't have php7.3 available on packages list.

Fixed, no help needed

Comment: Did you run `apt update`?

Comment: Yes I have ran $ apt-get update after updating the sources.list

Comment: I think this question would be better-suited to Ask Ubuntu since you're asking about OS-specific repos.

Answer (score 0):

That sources list only includes official repos but [there are no package names containing `php7.3` in the official repos for 18.04 (Bionic)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&keywords=php7.3). [The first Ubuntu version it appears in is 19.10 (Eoan)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php7.3). Maybe you installed it [from somewhere else like ppa:ondrej/php](https://www.cloudbooklet.com/how-to-install-php-7-3-on-ubuntu-18-04/)? See [How do I find out which repository a package comes from?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8560/how-do-i-find-out-which-repository-a-package-comes-from) on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, I've forgot I've installed additional repo on physical server.

Comment: @Tomasz no need to apologize :)